# How to replace all special characters with hyphen and also remove all spaces?

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to remove all special characters in a certain string and replace them with hyphen. All spaces need to be remove and also lowercase. is it possible to do it with 1 line?

An example: "HELLO - DI&RIC" -> should become: "hello-di-ric"

Comment: Note that you should not always go for the shortest solution. Your goal should be to make it as readable as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Following JAVA code snippet should work fine :

```
String str = "HELLO - DI&RIC";
String noSpaceString = str.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", "");
String alphabetsOnly = noSpaceString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "-");
String alphabetsAndDigitsOnly = noSpaceString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "-");
```

I have used extra variables for readability purposes. You can remove them to make it a one-line code, like following :

```
String str = "HELLO - DI&RIC";
String alphabetsAndDigitsOnly = str.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", "").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) method.
It accepts a Regular Expression and replace string.
I would probably first call [toLowerCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()) and then [replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) for whitespaces separated from the special characters. For the Regular Expression you probably want to use `\s` and `\W`, depends on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

a good fit for the requirements is Apache's [`StringUtils.replaceEach()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceEach-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-)

it allows to specify multiple search strings and corresponding replacements, and eliminate the need to fiddle with obscure regex patterns.
However, transformation to lowercase is probably easiest with the purpose made `String` method

```
String result = StringUtils.replaceEach("HELLO - DI&RIC",
    new String[]{" ", "&"},
    new String[]{"",  "-"}
);
result = result.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: this is good, but I'm looking for a more generic solution, not just for the '&' sign, but for all the special characters. E.g. It should also be working on the name HELLO - DI%RIC

Comment: @Nimrod you should be able to change it yourself using regex, though I am not sure if `replaceEach` uses regex and you might want to use Strings `replaceAll` method